# D3 - Prevent parent <g> element from firing click event

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, click

I am writing a program that is similar to the source code of 
[Zoomable Partition](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html)

I have added an image tag to each group element to act as a button to perform another action. So my structure looks something like:

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <rect>
    <text>
    <image>
  </g>
  <g>...</g>
</svg>
```

The code adds a click event to each  element that is responsible for zooming. I've added my own click event to the image tag to perform an action. When I click on the image my image click is firing, but also the g event is firing. Is there anyway to prevent this behavior so only the image click event fires?

Thanks for your time, 
LL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop propagation of the event to the next element.

There's an [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) that you can use in your event listeners.

If you want your onclick to work on the background / parent overlay and not the popup / child div Use the d3. Here is an example:

```
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="hl_main_popup">    
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  d3.select("#overlay").on('click', hidePopup);
  d3.select("#hl_main_popup").on('click', function () { d3.event.stopPropagation(); //stops the hidePopup from firing
</script>

});
```

Comment: Thank you! d3.event.stopPropagation(); in my image click function fixed it.